# How to update values in a collection List<int> in other collection LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

This works:

```
data.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.ClientIds = new List<int> { 111 };
});

return data;
```

But I don't want to create a new object, I just want to update the list like:

```
data.ForEach(x =>
{
    x.ClientIds.Select(v => { v = (int)sandboxClientId; return v; });
});

return data;
```

But in this second approach, my data.ClientIds still has old value.
Why?

What will be the best approach to update this collection?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring what you are trying to do here. You want to update the `x.ClientIds` list, right? How exactly do you want to update it? Set every element to `sandboxClientId`? Append `sandboxClientId` to it? Something else?

Comment: We'll need a little more details here, specifically - do you want to update the entire list of clientIds or just specific ids, and if it's the second option, how do you distinguish between values that needs updating and values that needs to be kept as is?

Comment: By doing `Select(v=> v=x)` you obviously assign some value to LOCAL variable v... Just iterate cliendids and set values using cliendids[i] = x

Comment: Sorry for not being clear here. @Sweeper @Zohar Peled
Yes, I want to update all elements of a `ClientIds` list which is `List<int>` type of object with some variable, in this case `sandboxClientId`

Comment: @Selvin but I have `return v;` statement? Should then this return update all values in list?

Comment: @TimSchmelter exactly, all members of ClientIds needs to have same value (`sandboxClientId`)

Comment: My advice: never use the `ForEach` method, it is really pointless. It doesn't make your code more readable, it's slower since it needs to create a lambda, there are side effects such as closures, and arguably goes against Linq principles (i.e. it's not a query, you can mutate the data)

Comment: "... all members of ClientIds needs to have same value (sandboxClientId)" meaning you want to keep multiple members with the same value? than why keep a list in the first place? just use an int

Comment: @ZoharPeled because I need it for API request model. (It's not mine API, someone else built it that way..)

Comment: What if you've had a list with only a single member? would that be OK for the API request?

Comment: I'm not sure. It should be the case like 99% of the time, but for any case, I would like to update all members with same value, just in case. Because I don't know what I will be getting from another endpoint for this request.

Comment: Are you just trying to do `x.ClientIds = x.ClientIds.Select(v => (int)sandboxClientId).ToList();` inside the foreach loop?

Comment: @Stefan0309 if you want replace the contents of the original list why not use a simple loop? `for(int i=0;i<x.ClientIds.Count;i++){ x.ClientIds[i]=111;}`. LINQ is for *Q*uerying, it doesn't update anything

Comment: @DavidG: i don't agree. [`List.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0) is an old method of `List<T>` which would not be part of the framework if it should not be used. Maybe you are confusing it with an extension method. Of course it can be useful if you want to make your code more readable. If this is causing a performance issue you are definitely optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's your opinion. Just because something exists doesn't mean it is a good thing to use (see `goto`). Not sure how you think it makes thing more readable? I hate this method and wish it was never added, which is pretty much the same opinion held by Eric Lippert I believe.

Comment: `Select` (as all other *real* LINQ-methods) are for *querying* data, not for *modifying* it. You should use a classic loop when you want to update items in a collection.

Comment: @DavidG: you are referring to [Eric Lipperts opinion about a `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) which they have omitted because a LINQ query should not cause any side effects but this method's sole purpose is to have side effects. But the difference is that `List<T>` is an in-memory collection and _not_ a LINQ query, so there is no reason to avoid this method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Partially, that came after a previous article. But even here he says "My answer was that I found it still distasteful on lists". It does not make your code more readable and can introduce closures which may cause more trouble. There is literally no good reason to use it.

Comment: @DavidG: well, E. Lippert was not the only developer at MS at that time, so others had a different opinion. But even E. Lippert says that at least "list is a mutable data structure" and that it makes it "more readable". I like to use a `ForEach` sometimes, because it makes it clear at first sight that it's  a `List<T>` and it makes it a one-liner, so probably more readable. It helps to make your code cleaner, because you should refactor the code which is used in the `ForEach` to a method, so you simply use `myList.ForEach(DoSomethingWithEachItem)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ClientIds` is a `List<int>` your 2nd approach doesn't work because you don't assign a list, you call a method that returns a value that is not used, you are not modifying anything.

So all integers should have the same value? Since `int` is a value type you cannot change it without assigning a new. So all you could do is to replace all items in the list via indexer. Maybe this simple extension would be useful(also for other use-cases):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ReplaceAllListValues<T>(this IList<T> list, T newValue, Predicate<T>? replaceIf = null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (replaceIf == null || replaceIf(list[i]))
            {
                list[i] = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now your code becomes:

```
data.ForEach(d => d.ClientIds.ReplaceAllListValues((int)sandboxClientId));
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Just a question regarding this replaceIf predicate. What would be a use case to pass it as an argument? (replaceIf == true)? I dont see any logic if its true? maybe this predicate is not necessery? And besides that, I see that you use generic object as input, so this will work for value types and reference types also ? For example List<string> ?

Comment: @Stefan0309: It's not necessary, that's why i made it optional. But since it's in extension method there might be a use-case where it would be useful. You see it's a generic extension so can be used for any type and even for arrays. It comes in handy if you don't want to replace all values but only some, you can pass in any condition for the type `T`. One example: you want to replace only negative values: `ReplaceAllListValues(newValue, i => i < 0)`